# Retrofit — Multiple query parameters of same name where name is set dynamically

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to migrate an old project to Retrofit library and this project has quite tricky API. So I have a query template like this:

```
@GET(value = "products/search")
Single<ProductSearchResponse> productSearch();
```

And I have to add some parameters here of following template:

```
filter[attributeId]=attributeValueId
```

For example:

```
products/search?filter[1]=10&filter[1]=11&filter[2]=20&filter[2]=21
```

That's how API works and I can't change it. I know that we can pass a list as a parameter, like this:

```
@Query("filter") List<Integer> attributeValueIds
```

But how can I also set parameter's name dynamically?

Comment: How many parameters do you want to pass, are they dynamic or just 4 like above example?

Comment: I receive a list of attributes, each of them having a list of values. And user have to pick some to apply a filtration (Like, if he wants to filter a list of products by color, he picks attribute "color" and then selects values "black" and "red", for example.) So "attributeId" and "attributeValueId" are dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link, posted by @ILLIA DEREVIANKO (https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1324), I've managed to solve the problem with this class:

```
   public class ProxyRetrofitQueryMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    public ProxyRetrofitQueryMap(Map<String, Object> m) {
        super(m);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        Set<Entry<String, Object>> originSet = super.entrySet();
        Set<Entry<String, Object>> newSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : originSet) {
            String entryKey = entry.getKey();
            if (entryKey == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Query map contained null key.");
            }
            Object entryValue = entry.getValue();
            if (entryValue == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Query map contained null value for key '" + entryKey + "'.");
            }
            else if(entryValue instanceof List) {
                for(Object arrayValue:(List)entryValue)  {
                    if (arrayValue != null) { // Skip null values
                        Entry<String, Object> newEntry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entryKey, arrayValue);
                        newSet.add(newEntry);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Entry<String, Object> newEntry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entryKey, entryValue);
                newSet.add(newEntry);
            }
        }
        return newSet;
    }
}
```

With this we can just use a map, where key is a unique parameter name and value is a List of Strings, that are values for this parameter. Something like this:

```
ProxyRetrofitQueryMap map = new ProxyRetrofitQueryMap();

    List<String> values1 = new ArrayList<>();
    values1.add("10");
    values1.add("11");
    map.put("filter[1]", values1);

    List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<>();
    values1.add("20");
    values1.add("21");
    map.put("filter[2]", values2);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an arrayList! Something like the code below.

```
@GET(value = "products/search")
Single<ProductSearchResponse> productSearch(
    @Query("status") List<Integer> status
);


ArrayList<Integer> queryStatus = new ArrayList<>();
queryStatus.add(0);
queryStatus.add(1);
queryStatus.add(2);

productService.productSearch(queryStatus);
```

Your url will be like that -> {url}?status=0&status=1&status=2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@QueryMap` annotation like this:

```
public interface NewsService() {  
    @GET("/news")
    Call<List<News>> getNews(
        @QueryMap Map<String, String> options
    );
}

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("author", "Marcus");
data.put("page", String.valueOf(2));

...
newsService.getNews(data);
```

More details: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap

Comment: I can't because if I do like this:
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("filter[1]", "10");
data.put("filter[1]", "11");
Then the key "filter[1]" will be rewrited and I'll lose value 10.